# Segmentation fault on Flask-SQLAlchemy query with sqlite3

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using the Flask factory pattern, and until recently was very uninformed about how to use the database object in an application context. Having understood that more clearly now, my code produces a segmentation fault whenever I attempt to query a model.

In a request, I have:

```
with current_app.app_context():
    eml = current_app.db.session.query(EmailList).all()
```

I have also attempted to query the EmailList model:

```
with current_app.app_context():
    eml = EmailList.query.all()
```

Both of these produce this trace from uWSGI:

```
!!! uWSGI process 2014 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 2014 ***
0   uwsgi                               0x000000010111d750 uwsgi_backtrace + 48
1   uwsgi                               0x000000010111dc93 uwsgi_segfault + 51
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fffb3ec9bba _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x00000000000000b0 0x0 + 176
4   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffb3860038 fillInUnixFile + 568
5   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffb385fc70 unixOpen + 2192
6   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffb385bab8 sqlite3BtreeOpen + 2856
7   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00007fffb3857a21 openDatabase + 1169
8   _sqlite3.so                         0x00000001026d8ac5 pysqlite_connection_init + 509
9   Python                              0x000000010129dad8 _PyType_Lookup + 1398
10  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
11  _sqlite3.so                         0x00000001026dcd3f init_sqlite3 + 1358
12  Python                              0x00000001012d710c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13560
13  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
14  Python                              0x0000000101279531 PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
15  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
16  Python                              0x00000001012d7045 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13361
17  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
18  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
19  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
20  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
21  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
22  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
23  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
24  Python                              0x0000000101279531 PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
25  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
26  Python                              0x000000010126640c PyMethod_New + 1221
27  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
28  Python                              0x00000001012a2283 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 5559
29  Python                              0x000000010129dad8 _PyType_Lookup + 1398
30  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
31  Python                              0x00000001012d67eb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11223
32  Python                              0x00000001012da4d5 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 485
33  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
34  Python                              0x00000001012da4d5 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 485
35  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
36  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
37  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
38  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
39  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
40  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
41  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
42  Python                              0x00000001012da4d5 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 485
43  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
44  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
45  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
46  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
47  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
48  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
49  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
50  Python                              0x00000001012da4d5 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 485
51  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
52  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
53  Python                              0x00000001012da442 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 338
54  Python                              0x00000001012d6eae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12954
55  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
56  Python                              0x0000000101279531 PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
57  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
58  Python                              0x00000001012d7045 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13361
59  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
60  Python                              0x0000000101279531 PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
61  Python                              0x000000010125b75b PyObject_Call + 99
62  Python                              0x00000001012d7045 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13361
63  Python                              0x00000001012d3a1e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1617
*** end of backtrace ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 2014) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 2015)
```

I create the db object in **database.py**:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

I use that db object in **models.py**:

```
from database import db

class EmailList(db.Model):
    # model definition
```

And I start it up within a **create_app()** call, also creating the tables in an application context:

```
from database import db
db.init_app(app)

"""Import the models."""
with app.app_context():
    from models import EmailList, BlogPost
    db.create_all()
    app.db = db
```

As I understand it, I should be able to use:

```
with current_app.app_context():
    eml = current_app.db.session.query(EmailList).all()
```

in order to access the database shared by the apps in the factory.

I am using sqlite for development. In the current_app_context, the database is correctly assigned:

```
What is current_app.db? --> <SQLAlchemy engine='sqlite:////Users/me/myproject/tmp/dev.db'>
```

How do I query models in my database? How I decipher what is going on in the trace?